# heroku not seeing table in db

Tags: heroku

I have an issue with my heroku db. I have a table named "views" when deployed to heroku the app is not seeing it and I'm getting errors. This version of the app was just git pushed, so it's identical to the one on my local, and after I ran all the migrations and restarted the heroku server, I did a `heroku db:pull` so my db should be IDENTICAL. when I run the app on my local, it's flawless, when I run it on the server I get an error in a view file that indicates it can't see the "Views" table.
This is confirmed when I open heroku console and run `View.new` I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant View
```

but when I run `View.new` on rails console I get:

```
=> #<View id: nil, user_id: nil, report_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

My main question is what are the differences between the 2 environments that lead to errors like this? Is there a way I can directly look at the db on the server? Would something like `attr_accessible`  in my view.rb cause this? I would think if it needed it, it would need it in both environments though... What gives?

I can post any of my files or error logs if you think thats the source of the problem.

Comment: my other question from the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371791/uninitialized-constant-error-only-on-heroku it holds all my code -- i figured given all the things I figured out it was appropriate to ask a new more pointed question.

Comment: your application can access other tables or that is the only one you have?

Comment: there are 4 tables. "reports", "users" "comments" and "views" all the other tables work fine. "views" is a new table added durring the last migration. I also added columns to existing tables, and those migrations worked fine. (the views migration ran with no errors as well)

Answer (score 0):

I need to learn about git.

I went back and ran `git add .` then committed and pushed and it all came together.